# UIScrollview stop at an image

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to create an image gallery app where the user swipes a UIScrollview and goes through the images. However, when the user stops scrolling the image stops in the wrong position. And this is what I end up with:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k7bW.jpg
I have been following the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaWnv5sRpho

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mainscrollview: UIScrollView!
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  
        mainscrollview.frame = view.frame
        
        imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "goku"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "boruto"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tail"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "sage"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "tobi")]
        
        for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = imageArray[i]
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainscrollview.frame.width,height: self.mainscrollview.frame.height)
            mainscrollview.contentSize.width = mainscrollview.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
            mainscrollview.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question can you answer it please 

Comment: Did you turn on "Paging Enabled" in Interface Builder (like at the end of the video)?

Comment: Thank you this has worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me with the scrollview although the paging was enabled. My solution was embedding UIPageViewController inside of a containerView instead of using scrollview.

Comment: I Have I found the solution just turn on "Paging Enabled" in Interface Builder. As said by @Andrew Bogaevskyi

Answer (score 1):

3rd party library - Reusable Scroll View for scrolling images should sort this out. Works out of the box. Applies the same principles as UITableView. Take a look:

https://github.com/sumofighter666/ReusableScrollView

You have samples there for both obj-c and swift. You can simply copy the code from samples